# Download entire S3 bucket recursively, node wrapper

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, npm

I am trying to sync my local folder with files from s3 bucket(full bucket dir structure). I tried using node-s3-client npm package but the connection to the package is failing. The process just exits without any output.
here are the code snippets:

```
const s3Client = require('s3');
let client = s3Client.createClient({
  s3Options: {
    accessKeyId: config.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: config.secretAccessKey,
    region: config.region,
  },
});
 let params = {
    localDir: localdirName,
    deleteRemoved: true,
    s3Params: {
      Bucket: Bname,
    },
  };
let uploader = client.downloadDir(params);
    uploader.on('error', (err) => {
      throw err;
    });
    uploader.on('progress', () =>
      console.log('progress: ', uploader.progressAmount, uploader.progressTotal),
    );
    uploader.on('end', () => console.log('Upload completed!'));
```

If this can't be resolved, please help me through a workaround, Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why you're using some random npm module for this when aws has their own fully documented and functional sdk. Use that instead.

Comment: @404 aws-sdk doesn't have the functionality for downloading, but it does have for uploading. I also do not want the cli option as I have to get this done on my node application itself

Comment: The `getObject` call downloads a file right? So you use `listObjectsV2` to find all objects, and invoke `getObject` for each.